# MySql hangs on update and insert

Tags: mysql

I have an E-commerce site, with many old products that are never used.

I wrote a code to find these products and move them to another table.

The code finds the products that should be deleted and mark them with column should_delete=1;

here is the code that copy the product (count = number of product to delete):

```
    while ($count>0)
    {
        if ( $db->Execute("insert into delete_product select p.* product p where p.should_delete ='1'  limit 500" )){
            $db->Execute("update product p set p.should_delete='2' where p.id_product in (SELECT `id_product` FROM deleted_products)");

        }

        $count-= 500;
        sleep(1);
    }
```

At first it runs very fast, when I do 'show processlist' I see that the query take 1 sec.

But then it become very slow, and queries take 1 hour.

I'm running on QA srv that is not in use by others.

I have lots of free disk space (3.5G)

there 80308 products in the DB.

and 29511 that are mark for deletion.

The db in innodb

it's is running for some hours now but only 6500 where copied.

The 'show processlist' show 'Sending data' state

What am I missing? why is these simple queries are so slow?

I was able to improve the second query -

```
update product p
join deleted_products dp on p.id_product = dp.id_product
  set p.should_delete='2'
where p.should_delete='1'
```

But the insert still hangs.

---

here is another version of the same code that also hangs -

```
    while ($count>0)
    {
        $fname = microtime(true);
        $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM product p where p.should_delete='1' LIMIT 500 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/".$fname.".txt'");
        if ( $db->Execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/".$fname.".txt' INTO TABLE deleted_products"
            )){
            $db->Execute("update product p join deleted_products dp on p.id_product = dp.id_product   set p.should_delete='2' where p.$should_delete='1'");
        }

        $count-= 500;
        sleep(1);
    }
```

This version hangs on -

```
 58 | root | localhost | prestashop2 | Query   | 29192 | NULL   | LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/1414615714.6019.txt' INTO TABLE deleted_products
```

it looks like the deleted_products somehow locks, but this is new table that I've created and no where else in the code it's reference, and no one else is using this srv.

Comment: it seems that I found a solution, I change the steps from 500 to 1.

Comment: did help, still hangs - 
| 74 | root | localhost | prestashop2 | Query   |  144 | Sending data | insert into deleted_products select p.*  from product p where p.should_delete='1'  limit 1     |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of disk space. I was looking at the wrong drive in `df -h`, I add more space and it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleted_products` table is increasing by every time this loop is going through. So when time goes on this part of your query is increasing:

```
 where p.id_product in (SELECT `id_product` FROM deleted_products)"
```

so imagine is starts with 500 then it gets to 1000,1500,... till it's very slow. Hence my suggestion is to add a where condition to it as following.

```
&AnAwesomeNewVariable=501;
while ($count>0)
{
    if ( $db->Execute("insert into delete_product select p.*
         product p where p.should_delete . ='1'  limit 500" ))
{
 $db->Execute("update product p set 
 p.should_delete='2' where p.id_product in
 (SELECT `id_product` FROM deleted_products where
 id_product<&AnAwesomeNewVariable AND id_product >&AnAwesomeNewVariable-500)");

        }

    $count-= 500;
    &AnAwesomeNewVariable+=500;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Note that I was able to improve this part of the query that u mentioned (see the end of my question). the problem is with the insert

Comment: @user1406269 it's probably due to your `where p.should_delete . ='1'  limit 500` condition since p.should_delete column isn't indexed it's gonna take longer time when the value increases. Hence my suggestion is to add an [index for this column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) as following. `ALTER TABLE delete_product
ADD INDEX product_ind USING BTREE (should_delete ASC);`